# How I can calculate the type of (> 0)?

Tags: haskell, types

Whenever I have an operator section with its left argument partially applied, i.e:

```
(0 >)
```

I just simply rewrite the operator in its prefix form and proceed with calculation:

```
(>) 0
```

How can I calculate the type of an operator section that has its *right* argument partially applied ?

Comment: You can always translate it with `flip`, e.g. `< 0` to `flip (<) 0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `(>)`, it doesn't matter, because both arguments have the same type. Remove either `Ord a => a` from `Ord a => a -> a -> Bool`, and you are left with `Ord a => a -> Bool`.

In *general*, you just remove the type corresponding to the applied argument. For example, given `(??) :: Int -> Char -> Bool`,

```
-- with the Int argument supplied, you still need a Char
(x ??) == (\y -> x ?? y) :: Char -> Bool
-- with the Char argument supplied, you still need an Int
(?? y) == (\x -> x ?? y) :: Int -> Bool
```

Comment: Great answer! Since you're doing an example and not the general case, you could consider using a monomorphic type for `??`. Say, `(??) :: A -> B -> C` or `(??) :: Int -> Char -> Bool` or something. This avoids the "uninhabited" problem and the "`b -> c` and `a -> c` are actually the same type" problem.

Comment: Thank you for your additional input to this great answer, @Daniel Wagner. Could you explain what’s a monomorphic type ? Could you expand on the “unhabitated” problem ?

Comment: @F.Zer For the present discussion, a monomorphic type is one with no type variables in it (though this is just a first approximation of the truth). The "uninhabited problem" is referring to what's mentioned in the answer -- namely, that the type `a -> b -> c` is uninhabited, that is, there are no interesting implementations of that type.

Comment: @DanielWagner Good point, making it general adds unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Thank you, @DanielWagner. Could you please give me an example of an uninhabited type ? I can't quite picture it.

Comment: @F.Zer Consider a function of type `() -> a`. This promises the *caller* they can get a value of any type *they* choose, as long as they provide the unit value `()` as an argument. But how could any function produce a value of an *arbitrary* type without knowing what the type? As such, the type is considered uninhabited, as there is *no* function possible with that type. (This is ignoring bottom, the unique value with type `a`, as you could "define" a function like `f () = undefined`. This make the *type checker* happy, but really `f` doesn't actually *return* at all.)

Comment: @F.Zer ...from my last comment: "the type `a -> b -> c` is uninhabited". Try it yourself! Write down the type signature `foo :: a -> b -> c` and then fill in an implementation for `foo = ...` that type-checks.